# Example use case of tmux's "refresh-client"?

Tags: tmux

From the man page (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/tmux.1.html):

> refresh-client [-S] [-t target-client]
>                      (alias: refresh)
>                Refresh the current client if bound to a key, or a single client
>                if one is given with -t.  If -S is specified, only update the
>                client's status bar.

What does it mean for a client to be bound to a key? I'm trying to think of when I may actually use this.

This is by default bound to "r" in tmux, and I'm thinking of overriding it. Could someone explain an example use case for wanting to refresh the client? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

tmux only updates the screen when there is some new content to display. If you put something like `date` into your status line, the date will only update when the content of the pane changes, when you change between panes, or when run `refresh-client`. So in that case, you could use `Ctrl-b r` to refresh the screen.

Alternatively, you can also set `set status-interval 1` to redraw every second, but that will cause CPU usage and drain your battery.

If you don't have anything dynamic in your status line, you can safely remap the key. And if you ever need to execute `refresh-client`, you can still run it with `tmux refresh-client`.

Comment: 8 years later and this is still a useful answer.